# loop over groups of Dataframe by checking values in consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a df, grouped by 'a'

```
a   b    c    b1   c1
1   y    nan  nan  nan
1   y    x    x    x   
1   y    x    x    y
1   y    x    y    y
2   y    nan  nan  nan
2   y    x    y    x
```

'b' is always y and 'c' is always x.

The first value of a group in 'c' is nan.

For each row i of a group, I have to check if b[i-1]!=nan. If so check b1[i]. If b1[i]='x' set c[i] nan. If it is =y set 'b' to nan. Then look into next row i+1.

same thing for c:

I have to check if c[i-1]!=nan. If so check c1[i]. If c1[i]='x' set c[i] nan. If it is =y set 'b' to nan. Then look into next row i+1.

Each group should be checked seperately.

```
a   b    c    b1   c1
1   y    nan  nan  nan
1   y    nan  x    x   
1   y    nan  x    y
1   nan  x    y    y
2   y    nan  nan  nan
2   nan  x    y    x
```

My attempt was to loop over each group (for-loop with 4 if's), but since it is too big I search for another solution.

Comment: Is something unclear?

Comment: sample of input is already there , please share a sample of output you are looking for